# How much memory is allocated in heap using new operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, heap-memory

```
int main()
{
    int ptr* = new int[10];
}
```

I wonder if in heap is allocating 10 * 4 bytes (40), and for the pointer also is allocated 8 bytes, or the whole line allocates only 40 bytes.
If for the pointer is allocated memory then 8 bytes are allocated in stack?

I am not sure but I think that for the ptr is allocated 8 bytes (IDK where), and for the block of 10 integer - 40 bytes (in heap).I just want to concretize. Thanks.

Comment: The pointer and what it points at are different things. Not fully grasping this is **the fundamental misunderstanding** that beginners have about pointers. In this case the pointer is on the stack, and what it points at is on the heap. `new` does not allocate the pointer, it allocates what the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: pointer is allocated on the stack (4 or 8 bytes depending on platform), but there are more than 40 (or 10*sizeof(int)) bytes - allocator has to add/allocate some bookkeeping information to be able to deallocate the memory block

Comment: The result of `int ptr* = new int[10];` is not memory allocation but a compiler message such as “error: expected ';' at end of declaration”.

Comment: The definition of `int *ptr;` and evaluation `new int [10]` are completely unrelated. As with any ordinary (e.g., non-`static`) definition of an object inside a function, it is simply automatically allocated, typically on the hardware stack. The compiler arranges for `ptr` to get the bytes it needs. Separately `new int[10]` causes dynamic allocation of memory for 10 `int` and produces a pointer to that memory. That pointer is used to initialize `ptr`. There is no other tie between them; nothing permanently connects that memory to `ptr` or vice-versa.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "of memory for 10" -> "of adequate memory for 10"?

Comment: @Bathsheba: The allocation is just for 10 `int`. That is all the memory that is reserved, as far as the program is concerned. Even if the implementation manages memory in chunks that require it to waste some memory when reserving the space for the 10 `int`, that memory is not allocated for the programmer’s use. If they access memory beyond the space for the 10 `int`, the behavior is undefined, even if the implementation is not using it for anything else. E.g., optimization could bollux the program if it does this. (I am extrapolating from the C standard; I presume C++ is similar in this.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Your presumptions are correct (insofar that I know C well enough to agree the comparison). As you know, I'm pointing out that almost certainly more memory than 40 bytes is grabbed for this allocation although (which is a common misconception methinks), as you correctly point out, there is no portable way of a programmer knowing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant `int* ptr = new int[10];`

Space for *at least* 10 `int`s is allocated (the C++ runtime library and operating system might actually allocate more memory than this, but of course you have no portable way of observing that).

That's `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes. On common current desktop systems that is indeed 40 bytes.

That memory has dynamic storage duration. It's assigned to an `int*` pointer type `ptr` which itself has automatic storage duration.

Comment: but the pointer *ptr that points to that block of 10 int-s, is also getting memory (8 or 4 bytes)?

Comment: @Dumitru: See my final sentence. On many C++ implementations that would go on a *stack*.